# How can I fix a VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA error in Integration Services Catalog?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis

I've recently switched from using Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2012, and from executing an SSIS package directly from the files on the server to using an Integration Services Catalog.

I am now the Integration Services Catalog execution is now failing because a new deployment of the package errors out with a VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA error.  In my previous environment I would fix such errors by opening the offending data flow component and resaving the file.

In the new environment I would have assumed that opening the component in Visual Studio, verifying that it is correct, saving the file, and re-deploying the package to Integration Services Catalog would fix the problem.  But now, the error persists.

I can manually execute the package from Visual Studio, which is what we've been doing for the last few days, but that's, er, not really a good long term solution.  ;)

I'm willing to entertain the possibility that the deployment wizard isn't actually deploying the new package.  (I'm quite new with Integration Services Catalog), but I can't even seem to figure out how to determine the most recent deployment date from ISC.

Can anyone guess what is going on here?

Thanks,  --sw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this package that errors out connecting to an Oracle database? I had the same issue a few months back. The issue seemed to be that when running packages from Visual studio it runs on 32 bit but once deployed they run on 64 bit unless you set up the job for 32 bit or specify when executing to use a 32 bit runtime. Long story short the 32 bit driver behaved differently than the 64 bit driver.
A few things that you can check - 
-try setting the DelayValidation property on the package to true
-Set the ValidateExternalMetadata to false on your source in your dataflow task task
-If you are not particular about 64 bit execution, you can use the check box in the Advanced tab to run in 32 bit mode.
Regarding the most recent deployment date if you right click properties at the project level there is an update date that you could go off... 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Setting the ValidateExternalMetaData to false on some of the problematic elements did the trick, although that seems pretty kludgy to me.

Comment: Why is the metadata is throwing an error? It's probably because something changed with the source. When I faced this situation, I preferred not setting the ValidateExternaMetaData to false and took another approach: 1) deleting the source from the data transformation 2) adding it back again. This synced up the metadata with the source.